# MySQL get duplicate rows in subquery

Tags: mysql, count, duplicates, subquery, rows

I want to display all duplicate records from my table, rows are like this

```
uid   planet degree    
1     1      104
1     2      109
1     3      206
2     1      40
2     2      76
2     3      302
```

---

I have many different `OR` statements with different combinations in subquery and I want to count every one of them which matches, but it only displays the first match of each planet and degree.

Query:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
  p.uid,
  (SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM Params AS p2
   WHERE p2.uid = p.uid
  AND(
(p2.planet = 1 AND p2.degree BETWEEN 320 - 10 AND 320 + 10) OR
          (p2.planet = 7 AND p2.degree BETWEEN 316 - 10 AND 316 + 10)
                            ...Some more OR statements...
     )
      ) AS counts FROM Params AS p HAVING counts > 0 ORDER BY p.uid DESC
```

any solution folks?

Comment: remove distinct

Comment: without distinct rows are duplicated but count is still same, note that subquery does not have a distinct

Comment: show the whole query and data

Comment: i put it in txt file i think that's the only way to show: http://flash.ge/query.txt

Comment: Who made that query? (is it automatic generation or made by man?)

Comment: i did,  it is not generated

Comment: I don't actually understand the second sentence of your original question. "count every one of them" you currently group the results by uid and planet, which means you may only get one row for each (uid,planet) combination. if you want more columns, you have to split up your "counts" column sub-query, if you want more rows, you should probably join instead of a select-sub-query. oh wait, i misread. it seems you don't know about joins.

Comment: You'd better make the statements more clear: for example there is no any kind of scheme and the second part of your SQL is not fully understandable. Use http://sqlfiddle.com/ for making the question clearer.

Comment: sqlfiddle crushes for my database (i guess it's too long).  i solved my problem thank you everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**updated**

So, the problem most people have with their counting-joined-sub-query-group-queries, is that the base query isn't right, and the following may seem like a complete overkill for this question ;o)

#### base data

in this particular example what you would want as a data basis is at first this:

`(uidA, planetA, uidB, planetB)`  for *every* combination of player A and player B planets. that one is quite simple (l is for left, r is for right):

```
SELECT l.uid, l.planet, r.uid, r.planet
FROM params l, params r
```

first step done.

#### filter data

now you want to determine if - for one row, meaning one pair of planets - the planets collide (or almost collide). this is where the `WHERE` comes in.

```
WHERE ABS(l.degree-r.degree) < 10
```

would for example only leave those pairs of planet with a difference in degrees of less than 10. more complex stuff is possible (your crazy conditional ...), for example if the planets have different diameter, you may add additional stuff. however, my advise would be, that you put some additional data that you have in your query into tables.

for example, if all 1st planets players have the same size, you could have a table with (planet_id, size). If every planet can have different sizes, add the size to the params table as a column.

then your `WHERE` clause could be like:

```
WHERE l.size+r.size < ABS(l.degree-r.degree)
```

if for example two big planets with size 5 and 10 should at least be 15 degrees apart, this query would find all those planets that aren't.

we assume, that you have a nice conditional, so at this point, we have a list of (uidA, planetA, uidB, planetB) of planets, that are close to colliding or colliding (whatever semantics you chose). the next step is to get the data you're actually interested in:

#### limit uidA to a specific user_id (the currently logged in user for example)

add `l.uid = <uid>` to your `WHERE`.

#### count for every planet A, how many planets B exist, that threaten collision

add `GROUP BY l.uid, l.planet`,

replace `r.uid, r.planet` with `count(*) as counts` in your `SELECT` clause

then you can even filter: `HAVING counts > 1` (`HAVING` is the `WHERE` for after you have `GROUP`ed)

and of course, you can

#### filter out certain players B that may not have planetary interactions with player A

add to your `WHERE`

```
r.uid NOT IN (1)
```

#### find only self collisions

```
WHERE l.uid = r.uid
```

#### find only non-self collisions

```
WHERE l.uid <> r.uid
```

#### find only collisions with one specific planet

```
WHERE l.planet = 1
```

#### conclusion

a structured approach where you start from the correct base data, then filter it appropriately and then group it, is usually the best approach. if some of the concepts are unclear to you, please read up on them online, there are manuals *everywhere*

final query could look something like this

```
SELECT l.uid, l.planet, count(*) as counts
FROM params l, params r
WHERE [ collision-condition ]
GROUP BY l.uid, l.planet
HAVING counts > 0
```

if you want to collide a non-planet object, you might want to either make a "virtual table", so instead of `FROM params l, params r` you do (with possibly different fields, I just assume you add a size-field that is somehow used):

```
FROM params l, (SELECT 240 as degree, 2 as planet, 5 as size) r
```

multiple:

```
FROM params l, (SELECT 240 as degree, 2 as planet, 5 as size 
                UNION 
                SELECT 250 as degree, 3 as planet, 10 as size 
                UNION ...) r
```

Comment: ok let's make some things clear, each player has 18 planets and each planet has its own degree, and yes i'm trying to find out which planets is near with another and so on, but the real problem is that i want to count same rows multiple times because one row can be matched several times in my combinations but my current query only gives me one row only once, and it skips next matches for this same row

Comment: now i'm thinking about this solution http://flash.ge/joins.txt , joining every statement (i have 182) what do you think? is it worth to try?

Comment: Question about the collision: may planets from one player collide or from multiple players (or both)? meaning which pairs of these may collide: (uid1,planet1), (uid1,planet2), (uid2,planet1). oh and your proposed join looks very confusing and like invalid sql ^^

Comment: Answer about collision: one players multiple planets can be collide with another players one planet, that's where i stuck because it only shows one collision ((uid1,planet1) and (uid1,planet2) with (uid2,planet1)). yea i know about invalid sql it was just for showing purposes

Comment: will adapt my post, this will take some time.

Comment: @BachoKekelidze done. hope this solves your problem. ^^

Comment: Thanks for the help bro! solution was the UNIONS!